# Mysql Warning Code 1592 - When performing UPDATE to replicated mysql instance

Tags: mysql, database-replication

[There are similar question on SO - but none that applies to this scenario]

I issue this statement:

```
update a 
join b on a.fk = b.id
and b.f1 = 1
and b.f2 = 1
set a.f = 1;
```

And get this error:

> 1592 Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format
>   since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an
>   auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe
>   because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any)
>   rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on
>   master and the slave.

From what I understand, this means:

- Mysql logs the statements performed on the master, and replays them on the slave to perform the replication
- If the statement results aren't deterministic, there might be discrepancies between the master and salve

I understand that if I perform insert based on a query with non deterministic ordering, and use auto generated id (or any other field) different result order will cause different values allocated to the id field.

However, this query updates an already existing record - just overwriting some of it's fields with a constant value. Specifically - I don't see any connection between the order of the inner query and the final state of the DB.

Is this query safe, or are there some other issues I didn't notice?
If not, is there a method to rewrite the query in a safe way?

Comment: We'll probably need to see the actual query and the table definitions.  The optimizer is (appropriately) aggressive when determining unsafeness of statements, so many queries flagged as unsafe are actually deterministic.  The best solution, though, is to use `MIXED` binlog format. Replication will then choose statement logging when it can, and row logging when it considers the statement unsafe, and these warnings will not occur.